# Is using possesive s okay with conceptual things?

Tags: grammar, phrases

This is my original sentence "The visual aspects of DDS narrative ..."

My professor says "The visual aspects of DDS's narrative ..."

Which one is better?
trying to avoid using double "of" like "The visual aspects of (the) narrative of DDS ...

Comment: I think both convey the meaning, but I don't know in terms of grammar, which one is correct.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know both of them work but my professor :)))

Comment: It doesn't make any difference whether the possessive refers to something concrete or abstract. I don't know whether DDS is a person - I would certainly use 'apostrophe s' if they are.

Comment: Hi.  What is DDS specifically?  What does it stand for?  Is it an organisation? Also can you give a longer quote in context.  It's hard to give advice based on such a small snippet. Please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: Disney's Alladin.

Comment: Your professor's change is fine and more grammatical.  There is no rule that says you can only use the possessive **'s** for a person.

Comment: DDS is Data-driven stories